# VS Code extension api get all selected files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing extension for VS Code and I'm wonder, if there any chance to get all selected files / folders in explorer / scm, when a context menu command gets executed?

Answer (score 2):

**How to Get All Selected Files in a VSCode Extension API**

Achieving this in a VSCode extension is straightforward. Follow these steps:

1. **Contribute a Command to the Explorer View:**

   Update your `package.json` to include a contribution to the explorer context menu:

   ```json
   "contributes": {
     "menus": {
       "explorer/context": [
         {
           "command": "MyCommand"
         }
       ]
     },
     "commands": [
       {
         "command": "MyCommand",
         "title": "My Command",
         "category": "Explorer"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. **Implement Your Command:**

   Register your command in the extension code:

   ```js
   const command = vscode.commands.registerCommand("MyCommand", async (currentFile, selectedFiles) => {
       console.log(currentFile);
       console.log(selectedFiles);
   });
   ```
3. **Select Files in the Explorer View:**

   In VSCode, navigate to the Explorer view and select the files you are interested in.
4. **Execute Your Command:**

   Right-click on the selected files, and you should see your command listed. Click on it to execute.

This will log the `currentFile` (the file that was right-clicked to invoke the command) and the `selectedFiles` (an array of all the files that were selected) to the console.

By following these steps, you can easily access the selected files in your VSCode extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official support for this in the Extensions API. This is something that has already been requested as seen in this edition of github:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3553

Comment: Thank you @Miguel, I've seen that tread. Looking forward when the feature will be available through API.